# Get WordPress blog content by url - python

Tags: wordpress, beautifulsoup, client, screen-scraping, xml-rpc

I've been trying to get the content from my WordPress blog. I have the URLs to each one of my posts, and I tried Beautiful Soup. But it seemed to require a lot of regex and still didn't give me what I need (only the content, nothing else).

So I'm using **`wordpress_xmlrpc`** now :

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import GetUserInfo
from wordpress_xmlrpc import WordPressPost

client = Client("https://sitename/xmlrpc.php", 'username', 'password')
all_posts = client.call(GetPosts({'number':50', 'post_status':'publish'}, results_class=WordPressPost))
print all_posts
```

This is giving me a list of my published posts. How do I get **the content** and not just the titles? 
(I do have a list of all URLs to my posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looks like this was an easy one. For anyone who's looking for this solution - First collect the ID of the post, then get the content.

```
one_post=client.call(GetPost(all_posts[0].id))
print one_post.content
```

This works, got it off documentation.